# Search and Highlight the search word in a string

Tags: java, android, text

i am using this code ... 
it's working well ...

```
  String x = showdata.get(SearchResults.TAG_SHOP_SECTION_ITEM_DESC);
    int positions[] = new int[100];
    Spannable WordtoSpan = new SpannableString(x);  
    int index = 0, i = 0;
    while (index != -1)
    {
        index = x.indexOf(MainActivity.SearchWord, index);
        if (index != -1)
        {      
            WordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), index, 
                    index+MainActivity.SearchWord.length()
                    , Spannable.SPAN_COMPOSING);
            index++;
            i++;
        }
    }
    itemDESC.setText(WordtoSpan);
```

however when using Arabic language it seems to break the search word from the rest of the string, since Arabic letters are connected to each other in many cases, not like the English letter which are not connected. So in Arabic the search word is found and has the color changed but also separated it from the next letter !

Comment: What is a question? What do you want? E.g., do you want get universal solution, or only for Arabic?